# Displaying number of correct answers for quiz app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm currently stuck on trying to display the number of correct answers once the quiz is finished.

Basically, I have created a state that keeps track of the number of correct answers shown within the QuizItem component. If the user selected answer matches the correct answer, then the user selected answer turns to green and it will increase the state of correctCount (as seen in the code) to 1. This new value is then passed to the parent component of QuizItem which is QuizList.

```
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
import React from "react";

import AnswerButton from "../UI/AnswerButton";

import classes from "./QuizItem.module.css";

export default function QuizItem(props) {
const [correctCount, setCorrectCount] = React.useState(0)

function addToCorrectCount() {
    setCorrectCount(correctCount + 1)
  }

props.onSaveCorrectCountData(correctCount)


console.log(correctCount);

  return (
    <div>
      <div key={props.id} className={classes.quizlist__quizitem}>
        <h3 className={classes.quizitem__h3}>{props.question}</h3>
        {props.choices.map((choice) => {
          const styles = {
            backgroundColor: choice.isSelected ? "#D6DBF5" : "white",
          }; 

          // React.useEffect(() => {
          //   if (choice.isSelected && choice.choice === choice.correct) {
          //     addToCorrectCount();
          //   }
          // }, [choice.isSelected, choice.correct]);

          function checkAnswerStyle() {
            /* this is to indicate that the selected answer is right, makes button go green*/
            if (choice.isSelected && choice.choice === choice.correct) {
              addToCorrectCount()
              return {
                backgroundColor: "#94D7A2",
                color: "#4D5B9E",
                border: "none",
              };
              /* this is to indicate that the selected answer is wrong, makes button go red*/
            } else if (choice.isSelected && choice.choice !== choice.correct) {
              return {
                backgroundColor: "#F8BCBC",
                color: "#4D5B9E",
                border: "none",
              };
              /* this is to highlight the right answer if a selected answer is wrong*/
            } else if (choice.choice === choice.correct) {
              return {
                backgroundColor: "#94D7A2",
                color: "#4D5B9E",
                border: "none",
              };
              /* this is to grey out the incorrect answers*/
            } else {
              return {
                color: "#bfc0c0",
                border: "1px solid #bfc0c0",
                backgroundColor: "white",
              };
            }
          }

          return (
            <AnswerButton
              key={choice.id}
              onClick={() => {
                props.holdAnswer(choice.id);
              }}
              style={props.endQuiz ? checkAnswerStyle() : styles}
            >
              {choice.choice}
            </AnswerButton>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
// create a counter, and for every correct answer (green button), increase the counter by 1.
```

In the QuizList component, I have set another state to receive the incoming value from the QuizItem component and use this new value to display the number of correct answers once the check answers button has been clicked.

```
import React from "react";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

import QuizItem from "./QuizItem";
import Button from "../UI/Button";
import Card from "../UI/Card";

import classes from "./QuizList.module.css";

export default function QuizList(props) {
  const [quiz, setQuiz] = React.useState([]);
  const [endQuiz, setEndQuiz] = React.useState(false);
  // const [newGame, setNewGame] = React.useState(false);
  const [noOfCorrectAnswers, setNoOfCorrectAnswers] = React.useState()

  function addCorrectCountHandler(correctCount) {
    setNoOfCorrectAnswers(correctCount)
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    /* This function turns HTML element entities into normal words */
    function decodeHtml(html) {
      const txt = document.createElement("textarea");
      txt.innerHTML = html;
      return txt.value;
    }

    fetch(
      "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=9&difficulty=medium&type=multiple"
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const dataArray = data.results;
        const newDataArray = dataArray.map((item) => {
          return {
            question: decodeHtml(item.question),
            choices: [
              {
                choice: decodeHtml(item.correct_answer),
                isSelected: false,
                correct: decodeHtml(item.correct_answer),
                id: nanoid(),
              },
              {
                choice: decodeHtml(item.incorrect_answers[0]),
                isSelected: false,
                correct: decodeHtml(item.correct_answer),
                id: nanoid(),
              },
              {
                choice: decodeHtml(item.incorrect_answers[1]),
                isSelected: false,
                correct: decodeHtml(item.correct_answer),
                id: nanoid(),
              },
              {
                choice: decodeHtml(item.incorrect_answers[2]),
                isSelected: false,
                correct: decodeHtml(item.correct_answer),
                id: nanoid(),
              },
            ].sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random()),
            id: nanoid(),
          };
        });
        return setQuiz(newDataArray);
      });
  }, []);

  // console.log(quiz);

  function finishQuiz() {
    setEndQuiz((prevEndQuiz) => !prevEndQuiz);
  }

  // function startNewGame() {
  //   setNewGame(true);
  // }

  function holdAnswer(quizId, choiceId) {
    setQuiz((oldQuiz) =>
      oldQuiz.map((quiz) => {
        if (quiz.id !== quizId) return quiz;
        return {
          ...quiz,
          choices: quiz.choices.map((choice) =>
            choice.id === choiceId
              ? // If the choice selected is the current choice, toggle its selected state
                { ...choice, isSelected: !choice.isSelected }
              : // Otherwise, deselect the choice
                { ...choice, isSelected: false }
          ),
        };
      })
    );
  }

  const quizItemComponents = quiz.map((item) => {
    return (
      <QuizItem
        key={item.id}
        question={item.question}
        choices={item.choices}
        holdAnswer={(id) => holdAnswer(item.id, id)}
        endQuiz={endQuiz}
        correct={quiz.correct}
        onSaveCorrectCountData={addCorrectCountHandler}
      />
    );
  });

  return (
    <Card className={classes.quizlist}>
      {quizItemComponents}
      {!endQuiz && <Button onClick={finishQuiz}>Check Answers</Button>}
      {endQuiz && (
        <div className={classes.result}>
          <p>You scored {noOfCorrectAnswers}/5 answers</p>
          <Button onClick={startNewGame}>Play Again</Button>
        </div>
      )}
    </Card>
  );
}
```

The error that I was getting is that there were too many re-renders, so I tried using useEffect on the setCorrectCount state within my QuizItem component (this can be seen in my code and greyed out) but it would not tally up the count.

Is there a good workaround to this problem? Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Link to the code via Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/quizzical

Comment: Your repo cannot run. And it is better to provide a codesandbox link that can run code online.

Comment: @MOLLY, its running. u need to run like this. `npm run dev --host` for this code

Comment: @MOLLY Hi Molly, I've imported into stackblitz and will update the question accordingly. https://stackblitz.com/edit/quizzical